# Fill Scipy Sparse Matrix with Ones

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy sparse matrix that I would like to replace values with ones:

```
from scipy import sparse
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 5], [6, 0, 0, 9, 10], [0, 0, 0, 0, 15]])

print sparse.coo_matrix(data)
```

I see that numpy has a ones_like() function but this didn't solve my problem.

The output should look like:

```
(0, 0)        1
(0, 1)        1
(0, 2)        1
(0, 4)        1
(1, 0)        1
(1, 3)        1
(1, 4)        1
(2, 4)        1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to manipulate the sparse matrix representation directly. The way to do that will depend on your choice of representation; for COO format, it'd be

```
data.data[:] = 1
```

Note that COO format has a weird feature where it allows duplicate entries. If a COO matrix has two entries at location `(1, 1)`, the above code will set both of those entries to `1`, resulting in a single entry of `2` if you convert the matrix to another format. If you want a single entry of `1` instead, you can normalize duplicates first

```
data.sum_duplicates()
data.data[:] = 1
```

Comment: If the original `coo` is built from a dense array, that `duplicate entry` feature (I happen to like it) isn't an issue.   It arises only when you build the `coo` from 'raw' data, row, col arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In case you only need to put ones in certain columns of your matrix, you can perform it using scipy.sparse getnnz function.
Using that function in the selected column along axis=1, you could obtain a new column with only ones in the respective positions.

```
data[:,col] = csc_matrix(data[:,col].getnnz(axis=1)).T
```

Of course, replace csc_matrix with the sparse type you are using, but take into account that slicing cols is more efficient in csc_matrix, so consider to transform your matrix into csc_matrix before doing this (if you have a csr_matrix you can modify this algorithm to loop in rows).

Comment: Can you comment on the speed difference compared to the accepted answer? I am concerned that the for-loop would make this inefficient

Comment: The thing is I was trying with the accepted answer, but I can't modify the data property of just one col of the matrix. I was trying with data[:,0].data = np.ones(..) and that doesn't work, it seems that it instantiate another matrix. I'm going to study the efficiency and I tell you.

Comment: It's much more efficient the accepted answer. The alternative way just performs well to modify certain column values (so I updated the answer).